# Can't decide how to test this code

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am attempting to write a test for the following code using mocha, chai, chai as promised & sinon but I am not too familiar with testing and have reached a mental wall.

```js
const PasswordResets = require('../../../models/password-resets');
const ResponseError = require('../../../error-handlers/response-error');

function updatePasswordReset(email, token, doc = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // If reset token already exists set it as the token
        if (doc !== null) {
           doc.token = token;
        }

        var passwordReset = doc === null ? new PasswordResets({ email, token }) : doc;

        passwordReset.save(function (err, document) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(new ResponseError(err.message));
            }

           resolve(document);
       });
    });
}

module.exports = updatePasswordReset;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please refer to [ask]

Comment: How would I go about testing this code? 

The part I am struggling with in particular is stubbing the passwordResets save method.

I need to write a test which makes sure this resolves with the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of the test that you can do as below

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const PasswordResets = require('...'); 
const updatePasswordReset = require('...');

const assert = chai.assert;

describe('test', function () {
  const document = 'doc'; // we will pass `document` for `save` callback func

  beforeEach(function() {
    // we use `sinon.stub` and `yields` for `save` callback function
    sinon.stub(PasswordResets.prototype, 'save').yields(null, document);
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore();
  })

  it('resets password successfully', function() {
    return updatePasswordReset('test@gmail.com', '1234', null)
      .then(res => {
        assert.deepEqual(res, document); // check if the response correct
        assert(PasswordResets.prototype.save.calledOnce); // check if it is being called
      })
  });
});
```

Ref: 
https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/stubs/#stubyieldarg1-arg2-

Comment: Thanks, this had been bugging me for ages! I had totally forgotten about the prototype...